# add some hours to time with microseconds php

Tags: php, time, format, addition, hour

HI I need to add 8 hours in the time which i have formatted like below

```
            $t = microtime(true);
            $micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
            $d = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro, $t) );
            $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u")   // 2015-03-02 07:37:18.715271
```

i use this format because i need to show microseconds also. Now i **need to add 8 hours** in this .Can you please suggest me how can i do this.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$t = microtime(true);
$micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
$d = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro, $t) );
print $date = $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");
print $new_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s".$micro, strtotime($date.'+8 hours'));
```

Comment: tghanks for the answer  but there is one problem  after 8 hours  it make 2015-03-02 15:57:42.00000   time like this i mean it makes microseonds all 0 .Please check

Comment: Sorry, try now. My bad. I fixed the issue

Comment: Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2). Note that date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas DateTime::format() does support microseconds.